# Smooth Overlapping Image Transition (Javascript Slideshow)

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

```
setInterval(function(){   
   image.fadeIn(1000, function () {
   image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images [i++] +')');
   image.fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Edit: Full Code Below

```
$(window).load(function() {           
  var i =0; 
  var images = [IMAGE1, IMAGE 2, IMAGE 3];
  var image = $('#welcome-bg');
                //Initial Background image setup
  image.css('background-image', 'IMAGE1');
                //Change image at regular intervals
  setInterval(function(){   
   image.fadeIn(1000, function () {
   image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images [i++] +')');
   image.fadeIn(1000);
   });
   if(i == images.length)
    i = 0;
  }, 5000);            
 });
```

The piece of javascript above fades the first image out to a white background, then fades in the second image.

How do I change the code so the transition overlaps each other, and the white background doesn't get shown.

Thanks!

Comment: Take the fadein out of the complete function of your fade out but I see you have made a typo so it says fadeIn where it should be fadeOut or you pasted the wrong code here

Comment: The code isn't correct, there is no fadeout and image is faded in twice, the first time with a callback. You're also missing a curly brace

Comment: Just posted the full code - since the first snippet seemed responsible for the images fading to a white background, I just posted that.